# Access all label from one import in component(LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel

I am trying to access label in a component(**Lightning web component**).

```
import greeting from '@salesforce/label/c.xxxx;
import greeting from '@salesforce/label/c.yyyy;
...
```

I want to access ***all labels*** in one **import**.

So is it possible? Reason is: one of my component have lot of messages which we need to import. we want to avoid multiple import line for label in my component.

I was following salesforce article but didn't get there:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_labels

Or if is there other way around, if we can remove multiple time import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think fundamentally they want you to reference the labels one at a time so that dependencies are properly managed. E.g. you can't accidentally delete a label that's in use, and if you add the LWC to a package it will auto-include the label.

If you have a large list of labels you want to use in multiple components, maybe you could create a utility component that imports all the labels and then exposes them bundled together in one object via an `@api` method. Then your main component will have a cleaner list of imports.

Comment: Can you please provide some line of code.